# __NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, json

when i am getting values from `JSON` php then i am getting issue for `__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString`:

My code is as follow:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        //convert to JSON
        for(id key in res) {
        id value = [res objectForKey:key];

        NSString *keyAsString = (NSString *)key;
        NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;
        //NSCFBoolean
        /*if([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        {
            printf("Number");
        }
        else if([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {
            printf("String --- \n");
            if([value isEqualToString:@"0"])
            {
                printf("Wrong \n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Right \n");
            }
        }*/
        NSLog(@"%@",[valueAsString class]);
        if([keyAsString isEqualToString:@"success"])
        {
            printf("Working \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not Working\n");
        }
        //Error is in below line
        if([valueAsString isEqualToString:@"0"])// strcmp([value objCType], @encode(BOOL)) == 1)
        {
            [self loginSuccess];
        }
        else if(strcmp([value objCType], @encode(BOOL)) == 0)
        {
            [self loginFailure];
        }
        NSLog(@"key: %@", keyAsString);
        NSLog(@"value: %@", valueAsString);
    }
```

}
}

Getting issue of `[__NSCFBoolean isEqualToString:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dc9964

Searching Google for this issue from yesterday, But No solution yet. NSCFBoolean is also not available in iOS 6.0, now. So what could i do to check "0" or "1" from `JSON` string? Please help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`value` is a NSNumber object (__NSCFBoolean, because NSNumber is a class cluster) and not a string! Use `[value boolValue]` to determine whether it's 0 or 1.

Casting an object doesn't change it's type!

Comment: Change `[valueAsString isEqualToString:@"0"]` to `[value boolValue] == 0`

Comment: `[value boolValue] == NO` would be better, and `![value boolValue]` would be best.

Comment: Great :) Thanks A lot Fabian :) found the correct solution after 2 days

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan Yeah I know, but I don't want to cause even more confusion ;)

Comment: Oh, i just accepted your anser now. :) i am new here. So didn't know about this before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the suspicious part:

```
if([keyAsString isEqualToString:@"success"] && [valueAsString isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
}
```

Either keyAsString, valueAsString (probably this one), or both aren't string objects. Why? We can't know this from your code, probably you do something wrong with your JSON data. Show us more code please.

**EDIT**

Try this :

```
if([keyAsString isEqualToString:@"success"] && [valueAsString isEqualToNumber:@(NO)])
{
}
```

Comment: keyAsString is fine but valueAsString is not working. Just checked

Comment: Print it's class like this: NSLog(@"%@",[valueAsString class]); It will surely be __NSCFBoolean.

Comment: Show the JSON dictionary please.

Comment: Is this you want?
The exact result without check - 

2013-02-02 20:17:30.620 Sample[2052:c07] __NSCFBoolean
2013-02-02 20:17:30.621 Sample[2052:c07] key: success
2013-02-02 20:17:30.621 Sample[2052:c07] value: 0
2013-02-02 20:17:30.621 Sample[2052:c07] __NSCFString
2013-02-02 20:17:30.622 Sample[2052:c07] key: cause
2013-02-02 20:17:30.622 Sample[2052:c07] value: Please enter valid username or password!

Comment: Tried isEqualToNumber with parameter (id *)value not with valueAsString because valueAsString is NSString type.

but when i checked as per your code then found another issue :(
__NSCFString isEqualToNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71d01c0

Comment: Wasn't valueAsString a NSCFBoolean?

Comment: No, valueAsString is as NSString. Any way i found solution by Fabian and its 
[value boolValue] == NO

Comment: But in this case the instruction valueAsString isEqualToString:@"0" shouldn't throw.

Comment: Its not "valueAsString" its "value". See my code above at line 3. its id value = [res objectForKey:key]; and i am using boolValue Check for value only. So its working. Finally No use of valueAsString now.

Comment: But you declared valueAsString = (NSString *)value; so they're the same.

Comment: NSString *valueAsString = (NSString *)value;


This line converting value, of type id or say NSCFBoolean, to NSString. So i was confused to check String or Boolean. but when i googled a lot about this matter then found that we have to convert this into NSCFBoolean. But iOS 6 deprecated this feature.

Comment: It doesn't convert anything, it just casts it, but casting is a non operation. So you should be able to do it this way: [value isEqualToNumber:@(NO)];